# Ionic framework - Remove the last view from history stack

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, back

I try to do the following:

I have 3 pages in this order: `mainPage -> econdPage -> thirdPage`

I want the back button at `thirdPage` to go back to the page before `secondPage`, hence: `mainPage`.

any thoughts how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$location.replace('thirdPage');
```

Instead of

```
$location.path('thirdPage');
```

It will swap secondPage to thirdPage in the history, and so the back will get you to mainPage.
Doc : [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#replace-method)

Comment: I'm using ui-router, will work the same? And won't it break ionic somehow?

Comment: Nop, under the hood it use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History and there is a replaceState so you will be able to do it.

Comment: I tried it, the first doesn't work at all.
 if i do
$location.path(thirdPage).replace it works, but the Ionic back button disappears.